# How to write trigger on after delete

Tags: trigger

I have checkbox Openop__c on account object. when I delete the open opportunities then checkbox should be false. I am new in sfdc. Could you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! the community here is more focused on working through specific problems rather than learning new concepts. Since you're completely new to Salesforce, I'd recommend working through Trailhead (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_triggers/units/apex_triggers_intro).

additionally, take some time to read [Ask] and take the [tour] and update your post accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you don't really need a trigger. Opportunity is a Detail object of Account. You could create a standard roll-up summary on Account indicating the number of open Opportunities. When the last one is gone, the roll-up field would become zero. You can use that to drive any logic that should come from having no open Opportunities left.

Comment: There is already checkbox and I have to achieve this through trigger.